# Deployed Web service

Tags: azure-ml

When I deploy my web service in AZURE Machine learning, is it possible to have NULL or empty in my test data set? Or I have to fill all the information to get the results of my prediction?

Answer (score 1):

#### In training set:

You would better use some methods to "presume" certain values...average / pro-rata......which you could find in various learning sources

Leaving them as blank (not sure of Azure but in a low level programming platform) would cause either inaccuracy or problems.

#### For testing set:

You are not changing the Learned Parameters, but still that would probably causing some inaccurate measurement but Azure ML may have done something internally.

Reference from [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/prepare-data):

> #### How to deal with missing values?
>
> To deal with missing values, it is best to first identify the reason for the missing values to better handle the problem. Typical missing value handling methods are:
>
> - Deletion: Remove records with missing values
> - Dummy substitution: Replace missing values with a dummy value: e.g, unknown for categorical or 0 for numerical values.
> - Mean substitution: If the missing data is numerical, replace the missing values with the mean.
> - Frequent substitution: If the missing data is categorical, replace the missing values with the most frequent item
> - Regression substitution: Use a regression method to replace missing values with regressed values.